# What is the difference between "ef - a fairy tale of the two" and "ef - the first/later tale"?

Tags: ef-fairy-tale-of-the-two

I'm looking to get the ef Visual Novel, on [VNDB](http://vndb.org/v88) there's apparently 2 different games for the English version, ef - a fairy tale of the two which is marked as a complete while there are 2 partials, ef - the first tale and ef - the latter tale

VNDB calls the game ef - a fairy tale of the two, the screenshots are ef - a fairy tale of the two and in the character profiles it says one of the characters is the protagonist of ef - a fairy tale of the two, however ef - the latter tale was only released last month.

there are Japanese releases of ef - the first/later tale which makes me think that what the English releases are based on but ef - a fairy tale of the two was released in English on Windows the day after the Japanese release of ef - a fairy tale of the two on the PS2 (never on PC)

I know that ef - a fairy tale of the two and ef - the first/later tale aren't too far apart otherwise they would be listed as separate games rather than seperate releases of the same game

so i am wondering, what is the difference between ef - a fairy tale of the two and ef - the first/later tale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ef - a fairy tale of the two* refers to the game as a whole. The game is split into two halves — [*the first tale*](http://www.mangagamer.com/detail.php?product_code=22) and [*the latter tale*](http://www.mangagamer.com/detail.php?product_code=97), which are sold separately, and they should be played in that order.

In other words, if you play *the first tale*, and then play *the latter tale*, you will have just finished playing *ef - a fairy tale of the two*.